# How to traverse the same table with nested cursors in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, database-cursor

I have a problem with an oracle procedure that loops the same table with two nested cursors.

Conceptually, I have a table that contains ten columns, numbered from one to ten.

Column number 1 must always have data because it is the primary key.
Column 10 may or may not have data as it would be like a child column, if it has no data it is a parent record, otherwise it is a child record.

I need to insert the parent records in two different tables, and the child records in only one of them.

For this I created two cursors, one that selects the parent records, and another that selects only the child records.

To the second cursor I pass the value of column 1 (which appears in column 10 of the child records) as a parameter.

The problem is that it does not enter the second cursor until it has finished with the first and I need it to read a record from the first cursor, enter the second, read those that exist, and return to the first cursor.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

From now on, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`) statements for your tables and procedure (please make it **MINIMAL**, so if you can do an example with 3 columns rather than 10 that would be good); the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that demonstrates the problem; a detailed explanation of how you want to transform that sample data; your expected output. Posting a question without any code makes it very difficult for us to know if we are answering the same thing you think you are asking; so make it easier and give us an example.

Comment: In the first step make some thoughts if you can solve it without an *cursor*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
begin

  for c in (select * from child_table) loop
  
    insert into table1
      select * from parent_table where column_1 = c.column_10;
  
    insert into table2
      select * from parent_table where column_1 = c.column_10;
  
    insert into table3
      (column_1,
       column_2,
       column_3,
       column_4,
       column_5,
       column_6,
       column_7,
       column_8,
       column_9,
       column_10)
    values
      (c.column_1,
       c.column_2,
       c.column_3,
       c.column_4,
       c.column_5,
       c.column_6,
       c.column_7,
       c.column_8,
       c.column_9,
       c.column_10);
  end loop;
end;
```